# Windows 7 like task bar for Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, taskbar

One thing I really like in Windows 7 is the taskbar. I'm wondering if there is some program in Linux which will give me the same functionality.

Here is the functionality that is important to me:

- I can pin a number of programs to the taskbar.
- Each of these programs can be started with a keyboard shortcut.
- If the program is already running, the keyboard shortcut switches to it.
- I can press another key combination to start a new instance of an already started
  program.
- Pressing the start program shortcut repeatedly cycles through open instances.
- Hovering on the icon shows running instances if there are any.
- Running instances and launch button is represented by the same button/icon

Comment: [Kustodian](http://blogs.kde.org/node/4038) for KDE attempts something similar. Keyboard shortcuts, by the way, are a function of the window manager, not of the taskbar. See [this](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/11619.html).